# How to import php HttpResponse object

Tags: php

I am new to OO php. I want to make use of the HttpResponse object, specifically the getLastModified() function. I tried

```
<?php print_r(HttpResponse::getLastModified); ?>
```

and it didn't know about the object. How can I import it?

Comment: Have you installed the HTTP Extension for PHP already?

Comment: Do you have  this class defined in another file? If so, import that file.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.setup.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to import classes in PHP as you would normally do in for example Java. It is sufficient that you:

- have the extension installed and enabled
- `include`/`require` the PHP file containing the class

The HttpResponse class is contained within the `pecl_http` extension, which may be found on http://pecl.php.net/

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I just downloaded the the extension, and I don't know where to put what. The php/ext folder only has dll files, but the thing I downloaded is a folder with a bunch of files but no dll files

Comment: You have downloaded the source files, which must be compiled to Windows. See the documentation of how to do this, or download the correct version from here: http://www.php.net/~pierre/